# jquery click event for checking one main checkbox and disable all other

Tags: jquery

i m trying to make a function in jquery to disable a group of checkboxes on click one main checkbox

**function is**

```
function DisableCheckboxes(id)
{

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
         $("input[name="+id+"]").each(function(){
            $(this).attr({
            'checked':false,
            'disabled':true});        
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $("input[name="+id+"]").each(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled',false);        
        });
    }

}
```

**and call it on click event as -**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#chkNotMatter").click(DisableCheckboxes('chklStatus'));

});
```

**problem is**
the click event donot gets applied and the main checkbox gets checked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass a **callback** to the event handler, and you are instead calling `DisableCheckboxes` and returning the result. You should be using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chkNotMatter").click(function() { DisableCheckboxes.call(this, 'chklStatus'); });
});
```

**Edit:**
As noted on the updated snippet, you have to use `call` on `DisableCheckboxes` because you are referencing `this` on it so it references the checkbox dom element properly.

Also, you can shrink your `DisableCheckboxes` as follows, because `attr` modifies all the objects in the selector:

```
function DisableCheckboxes(id) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $("input[name="+id+"]").attr({
            'checked':false,
            'disabled':true
        });
    } else {
        $("input[name="+id+"]").attr('disabled',false);
    }
}
```

Comment: this has solved the problem - main checkbox gets checked... but the main purpose of makin function that to disable all other checkboxes is not working..

Comment: It's because `this` in `DisableCheckboxes` no longer references the element, so in that case you have to use `DisableCheckboxes.call` to explicitely set the function executing scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#mainCheckboxID').bind('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      $("input.group1").attr("disabled", true);
    else
     $("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled");
   });
});
```